# If $f,g,h$ are functions such that $f \circ g=f \circ h \implies g=h$, how to prove that $f$ is injective?.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $f:B \rightarrow C$ be a function. Assume that for every pair of functions $g, h:A \rightarrow B$ such that $f \circ g=f \circ h$, we know that $g=h$. Prove that $f$ is injective.

I'm questioning about the validity of the theorem, if this theorem is true, I'm gonna try to show it:

Let $y_1,y_2 \in B$ such that $f(y_1)=f(y_2)$, I need show that $y_1=y_2$, but how i can show this?, I can´t say:

Let $y_1=g(x_1)$ and $y_2=h(x_2)$ for some $x_1, x_2 \in A$ because the theorem don't say me if $g$ and $h$ are surjective functions.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: The  assumption is "for all $g,h$"

Comment: @Max the question is still senseless... for every $g,h$ implies $g=\sin$ and $h=\cos$ but $\sin\neq\cos$.

Comment: @Masacroso  and ? I think you don't understand the question : there will be no injective $f$ such that $f\circ sin = f\circ cos$, and so what you're saying doesn't matter. The question makes perfectly good sense but OP needs to look at the quantifiers in it ( the title shows that he/she has not payed attention to them)

Answer (score 5):

Take two elements in $B$, $a$ and $b$, presume that $A$ is not empty, and presume that $f(a)=f(b)$.

Define functions $h,g$ from $A$, such that $h(x)=a$ and $g(x)=b$ for all $x$ in $A$. $f \circ g = f \circ h$, and so from the assumption we know $g=h$, and therefore $a=b$, proving that $f$ is injective.

Comment: Actually the statement is only true under the extra condition $A\neq\varnothing$. If $A$ is empty then from $g=h$ we cannot draw the conclusion that $a=b$.

Comment: When you say $h(x)=a$ and $g(x)=b$, you was take $g$ and $h$ like surjective functions. And the hypothesis don't define that in the functions $h,g$

Comment: @testpilot $f$ and $h$ aren't necessarily surjective. They map everything in $A$ to the same respective value. I'm not using any assumption when defining them - I have defined them explicitly.

Comment: @drhab Yes, you are right, I thought it's sort of implied from defining the functions explicitly, but I'll write it out.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is by contraposition. Assume $f$ is not injective. Then there exists $b_1,b_2 \in B$ such that $b_1 \neq b_2$ and $f(b_1)=f(b_2)$.

Fix an element $a \in A$, let $f:A \to B$ and $g:A \to B$ be functions that are equal at all points in their domain except at $a$. Let $h(a) = b_1$ and $g(a) = b_2$. Then we have $f\circ g =f \circ h$ but $f \neq g$.

Comment: If $A=\varnothing$ then no $a\in A$ can be fixed. The statement is only true under the extra condition that $A\neq\varnothing$.